# Integrating Angular2 site into ASP .NET MVC Area

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

Coming from the ASP .NET MVC world and learning Angular. I have an existing MVC project and I have added an Area that I desire to be Angular2.

I have developed the MVC project in VS 2015 and the Angular project in WebStorm. Both run individually fine but trying to run BOTH from VS 2015 fails for the Angular area.

My VS 2015 project is using IIS Express.

My MVC action routes like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return new FilePathResult("~/Areas/MyAngular/src/index.html", "text/html");
}
```

and produces this:

> Loading...

which is the index.html but Angular doesn't pick up the ball and run with it?

```
<html>
  <body>
     <MyAngularApp>Loading...</MyAngularApp>
     <script async src="/main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I accomplish this integration? I suspect the problem has to do with my IIS Express configuration understanding the js files....???